# What is the back end implementation of Google Drive's OCR?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using Google Drive's API to extract the extract the text from a PDF file. Does anyone know if the tool being used for this is tessaract? I'd like to know what the back end is for this before I start using it more.

The call I'm referring to can be found [on their API page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) under OCR.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: offtopic as its not about programming. otherwise explain in detail how the answer helps you or others in using the api.

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought that knowing how tools are implemented might help programmers be more comfortable using them. That's how I felt about this question anyway.

Comment: comfortable no, knowledgable about the tool yes :) its not the same. opinions about the brand of the tool are offtopic thus I marked it so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk#search_for_files) documentation and this [Google Drive Blog about OCR](https://drive.googleblog.com/2010/06/optical-character-recognition-ocr-in.html), the Google did not mention that they use Tesseract for this. But, if you check the [Tesseract information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_(software)), it is stated here that Tesseract development has been sponsored by Google since 2006. Sorry to say, but I think only a Googler that knows this OCR can answer or verify your question. Hope this piece of information can help you.